# Setting Options -Indexes recursive

Tags: htaccess

Is it possible to turn off all indexes for all folders without having to upload the options to every folder?

This is a shared hosting unix server, so server config is not available.

***Solved***
Even without server root, simply going one more level up (on Godaddy shared hosting plan) and placing an htaccess file with Options -Indexes is working just fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this related to \*nix systems? How? Should we assume you are running a web server? What web server? On what OS? Please [edit] your question and clarify, making it clear why this would be on topic here.

Comment: Unix editted...

Comment: What Unix? Most importantly, *what webserver*? I admit I'm not an expert, but I still don't see why this is related to the operating system. Wouldn't it be a better fit for a site like [webmasters.se]?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a \*nix issue.

Comment: @ChrisCox Please don't add answers to the question. If the accepted answer doesn't cover it, add a comment to the accepted answer. If that doesn't work for you, you could add an additional answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root directory (for you shared hosting account) add Options -Indexes and its will be inherited subdirectories

Comment: as in the public_html directory? Not sure I have absolute root access being a shared hosting plan.

Comment: When authorizing via FTP, which directories do you see?

Comment: I was able to solve it by simply going one folder up from the public_html file. It's not server root. But the host Godaddy got it done.

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this same solution work for csp headers?